# Something came out of oats. What's this?

Tags: grains

[image]

These came out of a rolled oats product.
Are these some part of oats and safe to eat?

Comment: Are there more of these in the container? Was it from one of those pre-portioned, pre-seasoned packets? What type of product was it (steel cut, old fashioned, etc.)?

Comment: @elbrant There were more and it's found in more than one package. It's plain old fashioned rolled oats.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like millet to me.

Your oats were probably processed in a plant that handles various types of grain and something was mixed.

It's a little hard to tell from just your picture but if it is millet then of course it is safe.

[image]